# Getting Error Promise is undefined in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-5, polyfills

I am converting React code to typescript,
target in tsconfig is es5.

on running in IE 11 i get an error "Promise is undefined"

I know i need to polyfill,but how?

I am not using Babel.

Following is my Webpack.config

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
var paths = require('./config/paths');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
//var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var AureliaWebpackPlugin = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');

var publicPath = '/';
var publicUrl = '';

module.exports = {
    entry: {

    app: [
    'core-js/fn/promise',

    './Generated Files/app.js'
],
    vendor: paths.vendorPath,
},
output: {
    path:__dirname + "/dist",
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: publicPath
},
devtool: '#source-map',
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
},
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
          test: /.tsx?$/,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
          //exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
          test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
          loader: 'file',
          query: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
          }
      },
    ]
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
      }
  }),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true,
    template: paths.appHtml,
}),

// For using jQuery
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: "jquery",
     jQuery: "jquery",
     'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
     'window.$': 'jquery',
 }),

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   "Promise": "promise-polyfill"
}),
  // new AureliaWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({/* chunkName= */name:"vendor", /* filename= */filename:'static/js/vendor.js'})
    ]
    };
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var ES6Promise = require("es6-promise");
ES6Promise.polyfill();
var axios = require("axios");
```

writing this above axios worked for me 
maybe other options also worked

it was mainly a cache issue in IE that i was facing

installing `es6-promise-promise` webpack plugin also worked

```
npm install es6-promise-promise
```

and include

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: 'es6-promise-promise', // works as expected
});
```

in webpack plugins

i will edit this answer with more possible options

Comment: Does not work for me... Error: Can't resolve 'es6-promise-promise' and if I leave only Promise: 'es6-promise' nothing changes, same error...

Comment: var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
put this in webpack and
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           Promise: 'es6-promise-promise', // works as expected
       }), in plugins

Comment: how do you use provideplugin? do you add this on the webpack.config file?

Answer (score 15):

You need to include Polyfill to make it work in Internet Explorer.

```
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise'; polyfill();
```

Include polypill for browsers/devices that need it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-io-feature-detection

Comment: Added explanation @jacefarm

Answer (score 8):

Add this script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

After that you can test in the console if the Promise is working in IE

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
setTimeout(function () {
    resolve('bar');
}, 1000);
});
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) [object Event]

Answer (score 6):

You need to add Promise polyfill.

Include polyfill in your bundle.
https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Load polyfill only if the browser / device need:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-io-feature-detection

Comment: how to add;

require(es6-promise).polyfill gives error in .tsx code;

should i add polyfill-io in entry path ie. app.js?

Comment: Include the es6 types as well with npm i -D @types/es6-promise

Comment: yeah i did typings install es6-promise

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [babel-polyfill library which can be found in cdnjs](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.2.5/polyfill.min.js) and offers a plethora of polyfills that I found useful for IE compatibility (including Promises).

Note that you don't have to use the babel compiler to use this; simply load the script and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

## As of Babel 7.4.0

ES6 Promises are just one problem you will have more such as the new assignment operator and more. There's a few things you have to do to get your React soloution working nicely for IE11

- core-js will provide most of the pollyfills you need (although an extra one is required for fetch)
- isomporphic-fetch - because this isn't provided by core-js
- are-you-es5 - The common practice is to not transpile your node modules, however some modules are written in ES6 or above then they just won't work, so you can use `are-you-es5` together with webpack to generarte `include` and `exclude` patterns of what and what not to transpile

### Polyfills

According to [@babel/pollyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) use core-js like this

**its important to note that @babel/pollyfill have advised to use core-js instead**

Answer used for a similar problem on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56750004/2423207)

```js
// install packages
npm install core-js
npm install regenerator-runtime
npm install isomorphic-fetch

// then in your entry point (index.ts or index.js)
import "isomorphic-fetch"
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

### Configure Webpack to transpile the relevant node_moduels

`npm install are-you-es5`

in your webpack config file

```
import {
  checkModules,
  buildIncludeRegexp,
  buildExcludeRegexp
} from 'are-you-es5'

const result = checkModules({
  path: '', // Automatically find up package.json from cwd
  checkAllNodeModules: true,
  ignoreBabelAndWebpackPackages: true
})

/** Returns the regexp including all es6 modules */
const es6IncludeRegExp = buildIncludeRegexp(result.es6Modules)

/** Returns the regexp excluding all es6 modules */
const es6ExcludeRegexp = buildExcludeRegexp(result.es6Modules)


{
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(t)sx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(j)sx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        exclude: es6ExcludeRegexp, // don't transpile these!!!
        include: es6IncludeRegExp  // tranpile these 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It took me a long time to get everything working for IE11 hopefully this will save people the pain I went through.

Comment: Although you are using ts-loader instead of babel, I presume that will still ultimately do the transpiling, so the exclude, include is still relevant

Answer (score 1):

Install these packages:

```
npm install es6-promise
npm install whatwg-fetch
```

Then update weback configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: ['whatwg-fetch', './index.js'],    <========== add whatwg-fetch  !!!! 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']},
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'index.html' }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
      React: 'react', 
      Promise: 'es6-promise'               <============ add Promises for IE !!! 
    }), 
   ],
  module: ...
```