# Internet Explorer Error - SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular CLI and show this message on IE9 "SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined".  I remove the comments on polyfills.ts and in IE10 and IE11 work, but in IE9 not.

Comment: did you add promise polyfill?

Comment: @AnsBilal This package https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill ?

Comment: yes and also go through this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533264/getting-error-promise-is-undefined-in-ie11

Comment: @AnsBilal Thanks! It is works! But show me other message "In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js" and this package I reinstalled but don't work.

Comment: import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; as an example in your e.g app.module.ts

Comment: @Domi  it is worked! Just in polyfills.ts isn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your src/polyfills.ts:

```
import 'core-js/es6/promise';
```

Comment: Tried import 'core-js/es/promise' but not working anymore. Something changed?