# React OIDC-Client IE Promise is Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I am getting "'Promise' is undefined" error on IE 11, Chrome and Firefox are not giving this error.

I am using below package for OIDC client, I already submitted an issue to that author as well.
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/826

[image]

[image]

If I click the link SCRIPT5009 I get directed to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/undefined-identifier

I installed below two, the issue is still continuing
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-polyfill
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

Also, I read articles on StackOverflow and on the web that promise errors come from using arrow functions and having ES6 code, but this issue is coming up within OIDC package so none of the code in the app giving this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install [es6-promise](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#es6-promise-polyfill) polyfill, You could refer to this thread: [Getting Error Promise is undefined in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533264/getting-error-promise-is-undefined-in-ie11).

Comment: the above package would work, but if you have a babel polyfill, that should automatically fix this.